# How do you layer imageViews in an android application?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, drag-and-drop, android-imageview

I'm trying to create my first real Android app, the code seems easy enough, but the layout is giving me problems.

My app will be a drag and drop application, very simple, just drag shapes to the correct place in the "puzzle". Here's an example of how it looks right now:

[image]

What I have currently is 4 `ImageView`s, one for the "empty puzzle" at the top, then 1 for each of the shapes below. I **think** the correct way to do this is to have each of the empty spots in the puzzle be an `ImageView` (what the arrow is pointing to, for example, should be an `ImageView`)

If I am correct on this, I need to "layer" `ImageView`s, put 3 "empty shape" image views over the "puzzle" image view at the top. The problem is I can't find any examples or suggestions for this anywhere online. So my questions are:

1. Does it make sense to have 3 `ImageView`s sitting on top of a "background" `ImageView`, or is there a more correct way to do this?
2. If I'm heading in the right direction, could someone explain/examplify how one builds `ImageView` layers?

---

XML for my current screen:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/emptyPuz"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/EmptyPuzzle" />
    <LinearLayout 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizantal" >
       <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView1"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:adjustViewBounds="false"
           android:src="@drawable/Circle" />
        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView2"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:adjustViewBounds="false"
           android:src="@drawable/Square" />
        <ImageView
           android:id="@+id/imageView3"
           android:layout_width="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:adjustViewBounds="false"
           android:src="@drawable/Triangle" />
   </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you planing to use the SDK drag and drop system or you're going to implement it yourself? If yes then go with 3 `ImageViews` for each of the empty images. If you're going with your own drag system then I would make a custom view to hold the empty shapes.

Comment: @Luksprog - I'm planning on using the built in drag-and-drop that was implemented in SDK11. I am planning on using 3 `ImageView`s because of it, but what I don't get is how I put that brown "puzzle" image behind the 3 "empty piece" image views that I'll add. Is that a 4th `ImageView`? If so how do I put one `ImageView` on top of another?

Comment: I would simply build a `LinearLayout`(or other layout) to hold the three empty `ImageViews`, set as the background for that `LinearLayout` the brown area followed by setting the empty shapes to the three `ImageViews` to the color of the background(I'm assuming you want to have a see through effect on the empty areas). To make it easier to build the shapes you could make custom views to draw them directly instead of using ImageViews.

Comment: @Luksprog - Thanks for the advice, I just looked into a background, that might just work for me I'll give it a shot. I haven't done anything with building shapes or using "custom" views yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I ended up using *was* to add a new `LinearLayout` with the `background` set to a "puzzle base" image and added three new images with "empty puzzle" pieces on it. Ie: I broke up each of the 3 "empty" puzzle slots into individual images like in this example:

[image]

Then used them as backgrounds to a new layout, so where I had this code before:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/emptyPuz"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/EmptyPuzzle" />
```

I now have:

```
<LinearLayout
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   android:layout_weight="1"
   android:background="@drawable/emptypuzzle"
   android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/dropsquare"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:tag="square"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:adjustViewBounds="false"
       android:src="@drawable/emptysquare" />
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/droptriangle"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:tag="triangle"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:adjustViewBounds="false"
       android:src="@drawable/emptytriangle" />
   <ImageView
       android:id="@+id/dropcircle"
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_weight="1"
       android:tag="circle"           
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:adjustViewBounds="false"
       android:src="@drawable/emptycircle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Ending with a resultant drag and drop game looking like:

[image]

It's not pretty, but my toddler likes it. :)